# Remove duplicated rows based on column values using awk or sed

Tags: bash, awk, sed

Here is the data file **df**

```
Gene    CHR Start   End Window
AKT3    chr1    243651534   244006553   355019
AKT3    chr1    243666483   244006553   340070
CBL chr11   119076989   119178858   101869
CLCF1   chr11   67131640    67141206    9566
CLCF1   chr11   67131640    67141648    10008
```

I want to delete the rows that are duplicated in **Gene** column and only keep one with the largest **window**.

The results should be look like this below:

```
Gene    CHR Start   End Window
AKT3    chr1    243651534   244006553   355019
CBL chr11   119076989   119178858   101869
CLCF1   chr11   67131640    67141648    10008
```

I can do that in R using the below code:

```
data = split(df, df$Gene)
data = lapply(data, function(x) x[which.max(x$Window), , drop=FALSE])
data = do.call("rbind", data)
```

But could any one told me how to do that using awk or sed?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `awk` you can do:

```
awk '!seen[$1] || $5 > max[$1]{seen[$1]=$0; max[$1]=$5}
     END { for (i in seen) print seen[i]}' file
CLCF1   chr11   67131640    67141648    10008
AKT3    chr1    243651534   244006553   355019
CBL chr11   119076989   119178858   101869
```

This awk command uses an array `seen` to keep only unique rows in it. This command also uses an array `max` to keep max value of column 5 for each `$1`. `seen` is populated first time or when current record's `$5` is greater than corresponding entry in `max` array.

To get **formatted output**:

```
awk '!seen[$1] || $5 > max[$1]{seen[$1]=$0; max[$1]=$5}
   END { for (i in seen) print seen[i]}' file | column -t
CLCF1  chr11  67131640   67141648   10008
AKT3   chr1   243651534  244006553  355019
CBL    chr11  119076989  119178858  101869
```

Comment: I added some explanation in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your file is Tab Delimeted
You can use the below code
`sort -t$'\t' -k5nr File|awk -F'\t' '!a[$1]++'`
**This is how it works**
Sort numerically based on the window column and then allow only the 1st record